# $\ a_{n+1} = \ a_n^2 - 2, a_0 > 2.$ , Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_k}) .$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Beeing given $\ a_{n+1} = \ a_n^2 - 2, a_0 > 2.$
I succeeded to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \infty$
But there appears the next limit : $\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{a_k}) = ?$

Comment: Have you tried to construct a successive-terms product for a small number of terms?  For example, $\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}(1-\frac 1{a_k})(1-\frac 1{a_{n-1}})(1-\frac 1{a_n})$ (assuming that the product had a typo...)

Comment: I haven't , I don't really know how to do that , I tried but I couldn't get a grasp of anything helpful

Comment: what if I transform the product into sum by applying x = e^(lnx))

Comment: Please make the titles of your posts informative as to the problem you are asking about "Please help me" is not informative.

Comment: roger that, I realized I should  do so after a while, sry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a_n=2\cosh{t}$, then an easy computation yields $a_{n+1}=2\cosh{2t}$.

An easy estimate shows then that $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(1-a_i^{-1}\right)$ converges.

Let $f(t)=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2\cosh{2^nt}}\right)$ for $t > 0$, standard arguments show that $f$ is well-defined and continuous, and that $f(t)=\frac{2\cosh{t}-1}{2\cosh{t}}f(2t)$.

Let $g(t)=\frac{2\cosh{t}+1}{\sinh{t}}f(t)$. Then $g$ is well defined on $(0,\infty)$ and continuous, and $$g(2t)=f(t)\frac{2\cosh{2t}+1}{2\sinh{t}\cosh{t}}=f(2t)\frac{4\cosh^2{t}-2+1}{2\cosh{t}\sinh{t}}=f(2t)\frac{2\cosh{t}-1}{2\cosh{t}}\frac{2\cosh{t}+1}{\sinh{t}}=g(t).$$

It is easy to see that $f$ goes to $1$ at infinity. So $g$ goes to $2$ at infinity, thus $g(t)=2$.

As a consequence, $\prod_{n \geq 0}\left(1-\frac{1}{a_n}\right)=\frac{2\sinh{t}}{2\cosh{t}+1}$ where $a_0=2\cosh{t}$.

As a consequence, your limit is $\frac{2\sqrt{a_1^2-1}}{a_1+1}=2\sqrt{\frac{a_1-1}{a_1+1}}$.

Comment: May I ask why you can approximate $ \ a_0 $ with  $ 2\cosh t ? $

Comment: I’m not approximating it, I’m choosing $t$ such that $a_0=2\cosh{t}$. That is because $\cosh$ is a bijection $(0,\infty) \rightarrow (1,\infty)$.